# Google Play Services Cast 8.3.0 change Holo to Material Design

Tags: android-appcompat, google-cast

We're still using Holo Theme and we're not yet ready to move to Material Design. But we need to use newer Play Services 8.3.0 (or at least 7.8.0) so we need to increase version in all our projects. We're using core library project which is link to our other applications.
Problem is that when we increase version of cast part of Play Services

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.3.0
```

whole application is using newer version of appcompat library than we declared. Without compling it with cast part of play service library everything is still Holo Theme and using older appcompat.
We're using:

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0
targetSdkVersion 18
compileSdkVersion = 23
buildToolsVersion = "23.0.0"
```

We already tried to lower above version numbers (compileSdk, ...) with no success. We also tried to exclude support libraries from cast library with:

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.3.0'){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

but again with no success to propagate this from our core library project to applications.

UPDATE: from `gradlew -q :projectName:dependencies` we're still getting

```
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.3.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:22.2.0
|         \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0 (*)
```

For coreReleaseCompile / coreDebugCompile (and other flavours) variants (exclude has no effect). Is there something else what should be set for library project to really exclude that newer appcompat?
Is there any other way how to disable using newer appcompat with cast library?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When using dependencies such as:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
  compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.3.0')
}
```

You can run **`./gradlew -q dependencies`** (or **`./gradlew -q :projectName:dependencies`**) to generate a dependency report. In this case, I get something like

```
compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0 -> 22.2.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0
\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.3.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0
     |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 (*)
     \--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:22.2.0
          \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0 (*)
```

As Google Play services depends on version 22.2.0 of the Support Library, you see that dependency override your 19.0.0 dependency.

Replacing my dependencies with:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
  compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.3.0') {
      exclude group: 'com.android.support'
  }
}
```

Led to the following dependencies:

```
compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0
\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.3.0
     \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0
          \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0
```

Which shows that the Support Library is being excluded properly. Of course, that certainly may mean that Google Play services will crash (as it may expect methods in the 22.2.0 Support Library).

Unless you have another dependency pulling in a newer version of the Support Library, you **can** compile with older versions of the Support Library.

I would double check your dependencies to ensure that you are actually excluding newer versions of the Support Library, but realize that version 19.0.0 is now **over 2 years old** (released October 2013) and specifically forcing libraries to use older versions of the Support Library by excluding dependencies is much more likely to lead to crashes.

Comment: I totally agree with you that this is not great idea to exclude those dependencies. If it will be crashing updating to Material Desing will be our first priority. I also updated question - exclude is not working for our project. Any other ideas why is that happening?